# Relation between the magnetization and the magnetic field in permeable media

Tags: electromagnetism

I am trying to re-write the constitutive equation of linear permeable media in a way that is more convenient for its numerical implementation. From most books I have seen that the constitutive relation is expressed as

$$\mathbf{B}=\mu\mathbf{H}$$

being $\mu$ the media magnetic permeability.

However, I would like to express $\mathbf{B}$ as a funcion of $\mathbf{M}$ using the relation $\mathbf{B}=\mu_{0}\left(\mathbf{H}+\mathbf{M}\right)$. If it is right the fact that for linear media the field induces a magnetization, I could write

$$\mathbf{B}=\mu_{0}\left(\frac{1}{\mu}\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{M}\right)$$

which gives

$$\mathbf{M}=\frac{\mu-\mu_{0}}{\mu\mu_{0}}\mathbf{B}=\bar{\chi}\mathbf{B}$$

now being $\bar{\chi}$ a susceptibility measure.

With this form, $\mathbf{M}$ plays the role of an induced magnetization. So, if permanent materials are considered, a new $\mathbf{M}_{0}$ should 
be added as

$$\mathbf{B}=\mu_{0}\left(\mathbf{H}+\mathbf{M}+\mathbf{M}_{0}\right)$$

Is this an accepted way to express the constitutive relation? Can you see any inconsistency?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written down does not look right.  The relation ${\bf B}=\mu_{0}({\bf H}+{\bf M})$ always holds exactly; indeed, it gives the definition of the auxiliary field ${\bf H}$.  So your notation already has a problem.

However, it seems that what you really want to do is to split the magnetization into two pieces:  a linear piece and another constant piece supplied by a ferromagnetic background.  Unfortunately, this is not generally a good approximation for ferromagnets.    In a ferromagnet, the constitutive relation ${\bf M}={\bf M}({\bf B})$ is not typically an affine function (constant piece plus linear piece).  The relation is actually extremely complicated and nonlinear, with saturation effects and dependence on the history of the sample ([hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_hysteresis)).  So your method is probably not going to be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Buzz! What I am trying to do is to obtain a law that can handle both permeable and magnetized media simultaneously. If we consider a ferromagnetic material then M0 would be equal to zero and the law reduces to the classical one. If we consider a permanent magnet then M is equal to zero. I agree with you that the last equation may be wrong... however I cannot see the problem with the relation between B and M.